# File.Copy not working - no error

Tags: vb.net, file-io

Please take a look at this code. For some reason that I can't figure out, the File.Delete() line isn't getting fired and I'm not getting an error.

```
    ' hard-coded for testing
    Dim path As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Program\Program.exe"

    Dim appDir As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    Dim iniPath As String = appDir & "\config.ini"
    Dim outputPath As String = appDir & "\output.ini"

    Dim textLine As String = ""
    Dim reader = File.OpenText(iniPath)
    Dim writer = New StreamWriter(outputPath)

    ' Read the lines in the ini file until the pathToExecutable line is found and write the path to that line
    While (InlineAssignHelper(textLine, reader.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
        If textLine.StartsWith("pathToExecutable=") Then
            writer.WriteLine("pathToExecutable=" & path)
        Else
            writer.WriteLine(textLine)
        End If
    End While

    reader.Dispose()
    reader.Close()
    writer.Dispose()
    writer.Close()

    File.Copy(outputPath, iniPath, True)
    File.Delete(outputPath) ' THIS ISN'T GETTING FIRED

    Return path
```

Comment: did you 'try/catch' in order to see an error?

Comment: whats the value of `outputPath`/`My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath`?  also where is this code located?  an event?

Comment: @ericosg, should've thought of that. The error message says the file's being used by another process, but I have reader.close and writer.close, so what else could be tying up the file?

Comment: i'll add a formal answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated that you are not getting an error, but if you don't implement exception handling, you're most probably getting errors and throwing them away (pun intended).

Use a try/catch around any of your System.IO.File operations, and even more, you can implement specific handles and catch specific exceptions.

```
Try 
    File.Copy(outputPath, iniPath, True)
    File.Delete(outputPath) ' THIS ISN'T GETTING FIRED

Catch ioException As IOException
    'The specified file is in use.
    MessageBox.Show(ioException.Message)

Catch ex As Exception
    'Some other error apart for file in use.
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Ericosg's suggestion about using a try/catch lead me to the issue: I had the file open in a streamreader earlier in my code, but never closed it there.